# How to reset z position to 0 when it reaches an end?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made my object move in one direction and reset z position to 0 when it reaches position 10. But position z does not returning to 0 when it reaches 10.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;



public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    float z = 1.0F;
   void Update()
    {
        
        if (z < 10.0f)
        {
            //move object forward
            transform.Translate(0,0,z * Time.deltaTime * 0.5F);
        }
        else
        {
            z = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `z == 0` is a comparison that returns `true` or `false`. Alone, it's invalid code. Perhaps you want an assignment (i.e. `z = 0`)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `.Translate` method moves an object by a specific vector. It doesn't assign a set position.

If you want to reset `z` position of a transform, assign a new vector to `.position` property containing the original `x` and `y` values and a `0` as the last parameter.

### Here's a fixed up version of your code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float Speed = 1.0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.z < 10.0f)
        {
            // Moving object forward
            transform.Translate(0, 0, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(
                transform.position.x,
                transform.position.y,
                0f);
        }
    }
}
```